# Java ResultSetTableModel resultset is closed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, resultset

Reworded this question as it wasn't very clear. My issue is that whenever the generateReport method trys to use model.getColumnCount() its returning zero and giving a ResultSet is Closed error.

However if I remove that finally block, everything works as expected. How do I do this correctly with closing off the connection?

Am I right in thinking that the model only lives within the createTable method as I've used

```
model = new ResultSetTableModel(rs);
```

Even though I declared the model as a class variable?

Method that creates the JTable

```
private void createTable() {                                         

databaseName = (txtQueryDatabase.getText());
String sql = txtQueryString.getText();
openDatabase();

try {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    model = new ResultSetTableModel(rs);
    tblEmployee.setModel(model);
    txtQueryCount.setText(Integer.toString(model.getRowCount()));
} catch (SQLException e) {
    errorMessage(e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    errorMessage(e);
} finally {
    closeDatabase();
}
```

The method that writes the file

```
private void generateReport(File file) throws IOException {
    file.createNewFile();
    BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        bfw.write(model.getColumnName(i));
        bfw.write(" | ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        bfw.newLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            bfw.write(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
            bfw.write(" | ");
        }
    }
    bfw.close();
}
```

ResultSetTableModel class

```
    public ResultSetTableModel(ResultSet aResultSet) {
    try {
        rs = aResultSet;
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        data = new ArrayList<Object>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] row = new Object[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                row[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        message.errorMessage(e);
    }
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    if (row < data.size()) {
        return ((Object[]) data.get(row))[col];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int count) {
    try {
        return rsmd.getColumnName(++count);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        message.errorMessage(e);
        return "";
    }
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {

    try {
        return rsmd.getColumnCount();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        message.errorMessage(e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It will help if you tell us what `ResultSetTableModel` is or give us the code for it. It does not appear to be a standard api class.

Comment: How are you closing the connection then?

Comment: After txtQueryCount there is a standard con.close(); etc etc block

Comment: How can `model` be `null`? `model` refers to the wrapper class `ResultSetTableModel`. Are you getting a null pointer? Can you paste the stack trace.

Comment: You're right, its not null - but why do I get the resultset = null error when it should have nothing to do with a resultset?

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) for better help , post the stacktrace you have, you are not demonstrating your issue

Comment: You can't save the `ResultSet` anyway, it will get closed when the `Statement` that produces it is closed. You don't appear to actually need it in the code you've posted here, or the metadata either. You need to rethink this class. Also you'd find life a lot easier if you had it extend `DefaultTableModel`.

Comment: Sometimes I just need to stop and think rather than rushing around.

Issue was I was using the instance of the class, not the table the values were stored in. tblResult.getColumnCount etc is the correct way of accessing the data, not classname.getColumnCount